# Using Async Task inside getview() method

Tags: java, android, azure, android-asynctask, azure-mobile-services

I have these lines of code , which i want to use inside `getview()` method of `CustomAdapter` .

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        final MobileServiceList<User> result =
                                mUser.where().field("name").eq(currentItem.getTo()).select("designation").execute().get();
                        int counter=
                                mUser.where().select("designation").execute().get().getTotalCount();
                        for (User item : result) {
                            // Log.i(TAG, "Read object with ID " + item.id);
                            desig[0] = item.getDesignation();
                            Log.v("FINALLY DESIGNATION IS", desig[0]);


                        }

                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    // gb.setDesignation(desig[0]);

                    designation.setText(desig[0]);

                }
            }.execute();
```

This is my AsyncTask code which , I am using to populate custom listview  .This piece of code keeps on running , I don't know how many times. But at the end it is giving me right results after so many updates on TextView (`designation`). This is not only degrading the performance of my application but also showing multiple updates on TextView before reaching to result.

I am getting data in `desig[0]` variable , have a look on my code .

Data is coming from azure But don't worry if you are not an azure guy . Just help me on Java part.

**QUESTION**

My question is how can use `Async task` inside `getview()` method . Do i have to make functions , which i can call latter . Data is coming from azure But don't worry if you are not an azure guy . Just help me on Java part. plzz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getView` gets called every time a line of list view must be drawn. So don't forget that there will be multiple `doInBackground` running at the same time. What is `designation` ? A view inside an element of ListView ?

**EDIT**

As designation is a text in each cell, you have to make sure that the cell you will upgrade is the good one. 
What I usually do is that I use a [ViewHolder](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) that I attach to the recycled View. Then I register the `ViewHolder` as a listener (listening to `AsyncTask`). 
`ViewHolder` starts the request and gives an ID to the `AsyncTask`. Then, while the `AsyncTask` is running, I periodically ask the `ViewHolder` if the ID that was given to the `AsyncTask` is the good one. If it's not, I cancel the `AsyncTask` (no need to be synchronous). 
Then when the `AsyncTask` is finished, I check a last time that the ID matches the one given by the `ViewHolder` and I notify the listener (`ViewHolder`) that the result is available. 
This way, you can be sure that the `AsyncTask` is not doing work for nothing.

But of course it will depend of what kind of task you are actually doing in AsyncTask...

Comment: yes ..designation is a teview inside each row of listview....and yes i already know that getview() is being called multiple times and so async task ...... plzzzz give me solution to avoid this....plzzz give me sample code if you have

Comment: thanks for the rply....I am accepting ur answer but .... can you give me some sample code...it will be very helpful then

Comment: Not now, but maybe later. Check http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching/ , it was very helpful to me. It will help you understand some basics that will be very useful later ;)

Answer (score 1):

Call the AsyncTask subclass in side Activity or onActivityCreated of Fragment and pass the result to CustomAdapter to update the view. If you can play your Activity or Fragment class to see where appropriate to put it.

Answer (score 1):

you need make a data model for you view. like make a class which contains all  display information(here a string for `desig[0]`). so you can update the view in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`.

or if you need the view only show when the `desig` got, hide it or add a loading waiting dialog when you getting the `desig` from azure.